# If dependencyManagement centralizes versioning of dependencies, what centralizes versioning of plugins?

Tags: plugins, maven, dependency-management

I would like to move specific declarations of plugin versions up out of the specifc poms into a higher pom.  The idea is to centralize the versioning of the plugins just like I do with dependencies via the dependencyManagement element of the parent pom.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

Comment: Ooops.  I was even looking for something called that . . . I sometimes find the maven site a bit hard to navigate, documentation wise that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pluginManagement/>
```

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management